# inner join to table depend on values in first table column join second or third table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have  four tables `User,Destination,City and visited`

as follows

```
declare  @user table
 (
   UserId int identity(1,1) not null ,
   UserName nvarchar(500)
 )

 insert into @user (UserName) values ('rahul')
 insert into @user (UserName) values ('nitin')
 insert into @user (UserName) values ('yunus')

 declare @destination table 
  (
    destCode nvarchar(50),
    destName nvarchar(500)
  )

  insert into @destination select 'SWDP','ranthambore national park '
  insert into @destination select 'BTP','ghana national park '

  declare @city table 
   (
     cityId int identity(1,1) not null, 
     cityname nvarchar(500)
   )

 insert into @city select 'jaipur'
 insert into @city select 'delhi'

 -- visited table in which user id with either destCode or cityId

 declare @visited table 
   (
     UserId int , 
     LocationFrom nvarchar(500),
     LocationTo nvarchar(500),
     LocType nvarchar(50)
   )

  insert into @visited select '1','BTP','1','city'
  insert into @visited select '1','1','SWDP','dest'


  insert into @visited select '2','1','2','city'


  insert into @visited select '3','2','SWDP','dest'
  insert into @visited select '3','SWDP','BTP','dest'


 select * from @user 

 select * from @destination

 select * from @city

 select * from @visited

  select * from @visited as v
   inner join @user as u ON v.UserId=u.UserId
```

Location type column in visited table denotes the `LocationTo` type. Its either city or location .

**Now i want to join these tables so i can get the data which user started from which city or destination and go to which city and destination .**

Expected result is as below image

[image: this is only for one user]

This is only for one user but i need same for all users .

Comment: Can you give a sample of your expected output for the query

Comment: just name of person from where he started and where he ends. just join  user table to city or destinations table depend on from where he started and where he ends .

Comment: @Tobsey i have attached image of expected result. this is for just one user name rahul .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if i understand your table structure correctly
but as i see it the table `@destination` can be both an origin and an endpoint?
and the `LocType` only specifies the type of the endpoint (`LocationTo` in `@visited`)
Given this i thik you have to assume that a numeric value in `@Visited.LocationFrom` specifies an Id in `@city`

then this query might be of use

```
  SELECT u.UserName,   
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(v.LocationFrom) = 1 THEN (SELECT cityName FROM @city where cityId = cast(v.LocationFrom as int)) ELSE (SELECT destName FROM @destination where destCode = v.LocationFrom) END as LocationFrom,
    CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(v.LocationTo) = 1 THEN (SELECT cityName FROM @city where cityId = cast(v.LocationTo as int)) ELSE (SELECT destName FROM @destination where destCode = v.LocationTo) END as LocationTo
    FROM @visited AS v
   inner join @user AS u ON v.UserId=u.UserId
```

Comment: yes you got the right point . @destination can be both origin and an endpoint same thing with city also. and i think LocType have no use as its only give me endpoint type. Yes numeric values denote cityId and short code like BTP denotes destinations.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you:

```
;WITH Locations AS
   (SELECT
        CAST(CityID as nvarchar(50)) LocationId,
        CityName LocationName
    FROM
        @city
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        DestCode,
        DestName
    FROM
        @destination)
    SELECT 
        Users.UserName,
        LocationsFrom.LocationName LocationFromName, 
        LocationsTo.LocationName LocationToName
    FROM 
        @visited Visited
        INNER JOIN Locations LocationsFrom ON LocationsFrom.LocationID = Visited.LocationFrom
        INNER JOIN Locations LocationsTo ON LocationsTo.LocationID = Visited.LocationTo
        INNER JOIN @user Users ON Visited.UserID = Users.UserID
```